# SQLite3 divide the result of two integers

Tags: sqlite

I have two queries and am trying to get the result of the queries through a division

```
SELECT AVG(quantity*price) from customerOrders / 
SELECT count(distinct orderDate) from customerOrders
```

The query is in SQLite3. Is the syntax wrong? Do i need to bracket it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are querying the same table in both queries you can do it by dividing the 2 aggregations:

```
SELECT AVG(quantity*price) / count(distinct orderDate)
from customerOrders
```

You could do it like this also:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT AVG(quantity*price) from customerOrders) / 
  (SELECT count(distinct orderDate) from customerOrders)
```

but the 1st query is more efficient.

Comment: How would I calculate the distinct months instead of distinct days?

Comment: With `count(distinct strftime('%Y%m', orderDate))`, but make sure that `orderDate` has the format: `YYYY-MM-DD` which is the only format that SQLite can use as a date for the function strftime().